Is it possible to show sub-totals to the right of the data, rather than the left OR hide those rows/column?
I don't want to show sub totals for rows/column when expand
I applied showTotals='off' property but it doesn't give the result what I want. It display blank cell.
Either shift it to right or hide those cells. I want to know is it possible with webDataRocks?

It seems that only hiding the values is possible. There is no property for shifting subtotals to the right or removing the blank cell.
